# How do I use sed to change },{"Foo" to }\n{"Foo"?

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I have a 55MB JSON file with a huge number of objects that are separated by `},{`.  I would like to have one object per line and get rid of the comma.  For one thing, I'd like to be able to look at the file using an editor, and most editors don't like files that are one 55MB line.  I used the following `sed` command, but it writes out a zero length file.  How can I achieve the result I want?

```
cat INPUT | sed -n 's/},{"Foo"/}\n{"Foo"/g' > OUTPUT
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: sed's `-n` flag says "don't print by default", and you're not printing in your sed command...

Comment: I'd recommend an actual JSON parser: `jq . <INPUT >OUTPUT` will prettify your JSON

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, I actually am using jq for another part of the project, but I never knew it could prettify the output.  That's awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-n` flag of sed means quiet. The automatic printing of lines is diabled then, and you have to explicitly print a line with the `p` command.

Just use your command without `-n` or with `p` at the end:

```
sed 's/},{"Foo"/}\n{"Foo"/g' file >output
```

Or:

```
sed -n 's/},{"Foo"/}\n{"Foo"/gp' file >output
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't have -n, then I added it as I tried different things, then I guess I forgot to take it out again.  Will try when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Took out the -n, presto magic all's well, thanks @chaos for the extra pair of eyes, and thanks again glennjackman for the tip that jq could prettify JSON.  I recently started using jq but I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects are separated by a comma, I assume they are in an array.

If they are in an array, and if that array is a top-level array, as in

```json
[{"Foo":"first"},{"Foo":"second"},{"Foo":"third"}]
```

... then you may use [the JSON processor `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to expand the outer array into a set of individual objects, like so:

```bash
jq -c '.[]' file
```

This would result in the following set of JSON objects, given my previous example input:

```json
{"Foo":"first"}
{"Foo":"second"}
{"Foo":"third"}
```

Since this alters the structure of the document, you may instead use something like [`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc), another JSON processor with a feature that allows you to pretty-print a document, just like `jq` does by default, but presenting the lowest level of each structure in a compact form:

```bash
$ jtc -tc file
[
   { "Foo": "first" },
   { "Foo": "second" },
   { "Foo": "third" }
]
```

Since you seem to want to explore the document visually mainly, you may also be interested in the [`jless` utility](https://jless.io), which is a sort of "JSON browser".  It would show the document's structure with (interactively) foldable sub-structures:

```
▽ [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  ▽ [0]: {Foo: "first"}
      Foo: "first"
  ▽ [1]: {Foo: "second"}
      Foo: "second"
  ▽ [2]: {Foo: "third"}
      Foo: "third"
```