# sed replace special characters with new line on Linux

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

i can handle the following case using notepad++ but i need to know how to do it through Linux.

**Input**

`football},{swim`

through notepad++ i can replace `},{` with `},\n{`

**Output**

`football},
{swim`

How can i handle that through Linux using `sed` or `awk` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use sed to change },{"Foo" to }\n{"Foo"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261338/how-do-i-use-sed-to-change-foo-to-nfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would replace every instance of the substring `},{` with the string `},\n{` (where `\n` denotes a newline character):

```
sed 's/},{/},\n{/g'
```

And here is what it looks like in action:

```
user@host:~$ echo 'football},{swim},{gold}' \
| sed 's/},{/},\n{/g'

football},
{swim

user@host:~$ echo 'football},{swim},{gold}' \
| sed 's/},{/},\n{/g'

football},
{swim},
{gold}
```

Comment: that's will not make sense with `football},{swim},{gold}`

Comment: Sorry, that was unnecessarily complicated. I guess I must be tired. I updated the solution. Is that what you want?

Comment: here we go :D yes that's works :D thanks a lot

Comment: Does not work for me: `echo 'a,b,c' | sed 's/,/\n/g'` gives `anbnc`.

Comment: @user9645 Which version of `sed` are you using? What OS are you using?

Comment: @igal - FreeBSD 11.3 , and sed apparently has no way to output its version, nor does it say on the man page, nor is there anything revealing when doing `strings /usr/bin/sed`

Comment: @igal - I now see the O.P. mentioned Linux (but did not tag it as such), maybe it only works with GNU sed.

Comment: @user9645 Yeah, that's what I figured. The same thing is true for me on my Mac - doesn't work with BSD sed. I updated the question title and tags to reflect that this question was specific to Linux.